# Error Handling ExpressJS and MongoDB

Tags: error-handling, express, mongoose

What is the suggested way of error handling in ExpressJS and Mongoose.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    Subjects.find({}, function(err, subjects) {
        if (err) {
            return res.json(err);
        }

        res.render('list', {subjects: subjects});
    });
});
```

I just returned the error in json. Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It depends on *what* that error is, but I would usually redirect via `res.redirect` to an 'Error' url, with details of the error.

You could test for the details of the error, and re-run a query (dependent on what the error is of course) but usually if the callback is throwing an error, it's terminal, so log it, redirect, and inform the user in a nice way.

(Or of course, return JSON and handle your response client side, with no redirect)

**EDIT**

As per comment from Paul -
I didn't mean to return the exact details to the user about the error.
Simply "Database error" or something like that would be more appropriate, depending on what the error was.

Comment: At the same time, you can console.log the errors so that an admin can see them or insert them into a text file on the server.  Telling the end user details about an error can be counterproductive.  A few may be attackers and then they might learn something helpful.  But most users, confronted with an error, will not copy it down verbatim and submit a detailed bug report.  They are just too busy and/or don't know how to do so with any precision. Expectations are also higher, things should just work and it is not their job.

Comment: Where to find a comprehensive explanation of the different error types in MongoDB?